# Facebook share dialog auto returns to app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a share button which share a post on Facebook. I've found this code below under Dialogs and UI controls on the Facebook developer page. It works just fine. The only problem is that after a few seconds on the Facebook post page it automatically goes back to the app without me clicking on anything. The below code is everything related to Facebook I've added, beside the `plist` Facebook app info.

How come it automatically returns to the app?

Code :

```
id<FBGraphObject> mealObject =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"cooking-app:meal"
                                        title:@"Lamb Vindaloo"
                                        image:@"https://example.com/cooking-app/images/Lamb-Vindaloo.png"
                                          url:@"https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html"
                                  description:@"Spicy curry of lamb and potatoes"];

 id<FBOpenGraphAction> cookAction = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
 [cookAction setObject:mealObject forKey:@"meal"];

 [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:cookAction
                                  actionType:@"cooking-app:cook"
                         previewPropertyName:@"meal"
                                     handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results,    NSError *error) {
     if(error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Success!");
     }
 }];
```